# Библиотека для рисования графиков

Tags: c#, графика, библиотеки

Здравствуйте.

Посоветуйте библиотеку для рисования графиков функций в C#. 
Функционал нужен минимальный, но крайне желательно, чтобы она умела рисовать функции вида f(x, y), т.е. двух переменных.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Рисовать графики* на формах в `.NET` позволяет [элемент **`Chart`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=RU-RU&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.DATAVISUALIZATION.CHARTING.CHART%29;k%28DESIGNER_SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.DESIGN.FORMDOCUMENTDESIGNER%29;k%28VISUALSELECTION%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29&rd=true)