# Библиотека C# для гистограммы с пороговым значением

Tags: c#

Хочу построить гистограмму так называемый "grouped bar chart" с "target line". 
то есть у какого параметра есть, например три характеристики. И есть несколько пороговых значений (паралельно горизонтальной оси идут "target line").Что-то вроде
[примера](https://docs.roguewave.com/imsl/net/5.0.1/chartpg/bar.html). Какую библиотеку выбрать? И можно ли не загружая дополнительных обойтись только `System.Drawing`?

Comment: Какая платформа?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/115679/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2?rq=1

Comment: WinFroms, WPF, Unity да хоть андроид, что у вас?

Comment: Проект Win Forms.